# Xamarin.Forms How to make centered SplashScreen fit on the screen

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to do something like Image AspectFit . I tried this:

background_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/code_logo"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
  <style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
```

The splash screen is showing, but the image horizontally is bigger then the screen and its not fit. Maybe the problem is because my image logo is 3500 x 1360 ? I just need to fit in the screen. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Image logo is too large, you can set the `width` and `Height` for your `item` of `bitmap` like following code.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

  <item   android:width="200dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"> 
    <bitmap
         android:gravity="fill"
         android:mipMap="true"
         android:src="@drawable/code_logo"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

My test code_logo is 3500 x 1360, due to width is too large, emulator sometimes will crash. Please reduce the size of the logo by the width and height ratio, and set the with or height like above code.
[image]

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. I researched the image is so big

Comment: Just one more question how dp works on multiple screens?